# Binary Algebra Clarification

Tags: java, binary, algebra

I need some clarification with some binary algebra.

A(C+D'B)+A'

Where A = 1, B = 0, C = 1, D = 0

So -> 1(1+1*0)+0

My understanding is that OR is defined as the + operating and AND is defined as no operator or the * operator

So (1+1) = 1, (1*0) = 0, then 1(0) = 0, then 0*0 = 0

Am I understanding this correctly? Is there some known program that can check this for me? I shouldn't distribution that 1 because it's not multiplication correct?

Another thing, regarding order of operations. I understand that parenthesis come first. But for AND and OR, isn't it the same as when multiplication and division are in an equation. Sure multiplication comes first in PEMDAS(Parentheses, exponents, multiplication,division, addition, subtraction) But you evaluate multiplication and division from left to right.

I am trying to create a method in Java to give an answer based on input from the user. (Basically a calculator)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not really programming related. Perhaps it would be better asked at http://math.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Still consider the operator precedence (that PEMDAS) `1+1*0 = 1+(1*0) = 1+0 = 1`